# How to use select query in mysql update trigger

Tags: mysql

### Description :

I want to use a select query in MySQL to update a trigger.

### Tables columns :

1) order : id, final_price, products_price, send_price, discount_price, turnover_id, turnover_credit_id

2) turnovers : id, price

3) turnover_credits : id, price

### My results :

The following query works correctly :

```
CREATE TRIGGER test
BEFORE UPDATE ON orders
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.final_price = 
      NEW.product_price
    + NEW.send_price 
    - NEW.discount_price
```

But the following queries have failed:

```
SET NEW.final_price = 
      NEW.total_price 
    + NEW.send_price 
    - NEW.discount_price 
    - SELECT IFNULL((SELECT t.price FROM turnovers AS t WHERE t.id=NEW.turnover_id), 0)
    - SELECT IFNULL((SELECT tc.price FROM turnover_credits AS tc WHERE tc.id=NEW.turnover_credit_id), 0)


SET NEW.final_price = 
      NEW.total_price 
    + NEW.send_price 
    - NEW.discount_price 
    - SELECT CAST(IFNULL((SELECT t.price FROM turnovers AS t WHERE t.id = NEW.turnover_id ) , 0 ) AS SIGNED ) 
    - SELECT CAST(IFNULL((SELECT tc.price FROM turnover_credits AS tc WHERE tc.id=NEW.turnover_credit_id), 0) AS SIGNED)

SET NEW.final_price = 
      NEW.total_price 
    + NEW.send_price 
    - NEW.discount_price 
    - CAST(SELECT CAST(IFNULL((SELECT t.price FROM turnovers AS t WHERE t.id=NEW.turnover_id), 0) AS SIGNED) AS SIGNED) 
    - CAST(SELECT CAST(IFNULL((SELECT tc.price FROM turnover_credits AS tc WHERE tc.id = NEW.turnover_credit_id ), 0) AS SIGNED) AS SIGNED)
```

After runnig the above query, MySQL error message is :

```
The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER... NEW.discount_price "
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'SELECT CAST(IFNULL((SELECT t.price FROM turnovers AS t WHERE t.id=NEW.turnover_id), 0) AS SIGNED)' at line 8
```

### Please Help me.

### Thanks a lot.

Comment: Every statement must be terminated.Sub queries must be within parentheses.()

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your suggestion did not work.

Comment: It wasn't an answer it was a comment - you could help yourself if you published the full code for the create together with your table definitions,sample data and expected output - as text in the question or as a sql fiddle

Comment: [P.Salmon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6152400/p-salmon)! After I removed the cast function from my query, your suggestion works. Thank you.